# Azure Active Directory Gather Password Hashes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hi I've looked all over the web and can't find a way to dump user accounts and password hashes from Azure Active Directory. My company is trying to migrate without forcing password changes to the entire company and it would be very helpful to export their previous account and password hash from Azure. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract password hashes from Azure AD.
There is no API allowing that.